# Setup Firmata for PC-less usage

Tags: arduino-uno, firmata

I want to use an Arduino Uno with Firmata as a standalone datalogger for recording analog signals. I will use power banks to power the Arduino. How is it possible to setup Firmata pins once with PC and use that battery powered in PC-less situation?

Comment: how do you want to use Firmata without computer? Arduino with Firmata is a slave that can do nothing without commands from master